# Developing application on OnePlus

Tags: android, settings, oneplusone

I'm trying to develop an android application on Android Studio.

I have a OnePlus device from Cyanogen with android version of 4.4.4.

I enabled the developer options and enabled the USB debugging but when I connect the phone to the laptop to run the application, the Android studio does not recognize the device and I cannot chose it to run the application on it.

I can see the device on My Computer as another driver and can view the files on the phone so the laptop does recognize the phone but the Android studio does not.

What do I need to change on my phone's settings to run developing applications on it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install adb driver.

If you can see an unknown device, you can right click it and select *%your-sdk-dir%\extras\google\usb_driver\%i386 or amd64%* to install.

Or you can enter *%your-sdk-dir%\extras\google\usb_driver*, and right click "android_winusb.inf" and select install to install the adb driver.

Or you can install something like "91 assistant" on you computer, it will install the adb driver when your phone is connected.

When adb driver is properly installed, you should see a device name "Android Phone", and android studio should recognize your phone.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Mac or Linux computer it should see it automatically. 
If you are using Windows, you should install debugging drivers.

You can install it in Android SDK Manager found in Android Studio.

You can see in the below screenshot that there is Google USB Driver that is not compatible with Mac OS.

[image]

Comment: I downloaded yesterday all the packages that the SDK had. I don't think this is my problem. When I connect a friend's Nexus 4 I can see it when I try to run the application. By the way, I'm using windows 8.

Comment: If you are seeing the device as a unknown device in your Windows Device settings, you can right click it and try to install the driver manually. You should point it to the extras folder in your sdk folder.

Comment: What does it output when you write `adb devices` in command line?